# Asus tuf gaming FX505dt - fan control

Tags: asus, fan, fancontrol

Is there any way to control fan in ASUS TUF GAMING FX505DT? I tried the lm-sensors, but when I try to type `sudo pwmconfig` I'm getting

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

I also tried `thermald`, but I'm getting this when doing `sudo thermald --no-daemon --ignore-cpuid-check`

```
[WARN]NO RAPL sysfs present 
[WARN]Polling mode is enabled: 4
[WARN]Thermal DTS: No coretemp sysfs found
[WARN]sensor id 2 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon5/power1_average: No temp sysfs for reading raw temp
[WARN]sensor id 2 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon5/power1_average: No temp sysfs for reading raw temp
[WARN]sysfs open failed 
[WARN]sysfs open failed 
[WARN]sysfs open failed /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
[ERR]Thermal DTS or hwmon: No Zones present Need to configure manually
[ERR]XML zone: invalid sensor type x86_pkg_temp
```

My fan is very loud, when doing nothing 2400RPM, most of the time 3500+ rpm, I just wonder if it's even possible to control fan speed?